# Add Link from page to Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

What i want to do is, before you click on the link that will get you to other web page is that i want to add lightbox to all "'add' class" links which will inform you that you are leaving this page. In that lightbox i want that link to appear you just used to open this lightbox.

What i have accomplish so far is i get the lightbox to appear but it cuts out the hole link from page and paste it in the lightbox, also if you want to click that link nothing is happening because it try to open that lightbox again.

HTML:

```
<div class="add"><a href="http://www.jsfiddle.net/" id="add_btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="btn">Add</a></div>
```

Code:

```
$(".add").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterLoad   : function() {

this.inner.prepend( '<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque blandit, mi sed sollicitudin hendrerit, elit elit tristique velit</h4>' );

this.add = '<a href="' + this.href + '"></a>' 
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2pyAP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want is :

- click a link in page "A" that points to a webpage "B"
- instead of going to page "B", show a lightbox asking for confirmation before leaving page "A"
- if visitor say "yes", then proceed to page "B", otherwise close lightbox and stay in page "A"

If all of the above is correct, then I would set the confirmation content of fancybox inside a variable like :

```
var confirm = "<div class='confirm'>" +
    "<p>You are about to leave this page.</p>" +
    "<p>Are you sure you want to do that?</p><br />" +
    "<a href='#' class='button yes'>Yes</a>" +
    "<a href='#' class='button no'>no</a>" +
    "</div>";
```

Then catch the value of the `href` attribute of the clicked link in another variable, using the `afterLoad` callback.

Then bind a `click` to the `.button` selector (within the `confirm` variable as above) within the `afterShow` callback and decide what action to take, either :

- got to page "B"
- close fancybox and stay in page "A"

Assuming that you have a link like this :

```
<a href="http://www.jsfiddle.net/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="fancybox">Add</a>
```

... here the code to do so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "html", // because the content will be the "confirm" variable
        modal: true, // avoids closing fancybox but clicking "yes" or "no"
        afterLoad: function () {
            link = this.href; // page "B" URL
            this.content = confirm; // set fancybox content
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            // bind click to both buttons yes and no
            $(".button").on("click", function (event) {
                if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass("yes")) {
                    location.href = link; // go to page "B"
                } else if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass("no")) {
                    $.fancybox.close(); // close fancybox and stay in page "A"
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4u7U4/)</kbd>

---

**EDIT** (Feb 15, 2014) :

The OP said:

> I'm trying now to open the link in new tab window when click "yes"

to do so, change this part

```
if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass("yes")) {
    location.href = link; // go to page "B"
}
```

into this

```
if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass("yes")) {
    //location.href = link; // go to page "B"
    window.open(link); // open in a new tab
    $.fancybox.close(); // optional, otherwise fancybox will remain open
}
```

See updated <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4u7U4/43/)</kbd>

Comment: I'm trying now to open the link in new tab window when click "yes"

I try to use this code under function (event) without success 
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
window.open(this.href, '_blank');